# link error 2001 when compiling maya plugin example

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

I'm trying to compile the maya example plugin manipOverride from the devkit, but got several link errors below:

`error LNK2001: unsolved external reference "public: virtual class MStatus __cdecl MPxNode::dependsOn(class MPlug const &,class MPlug const &,bool &)const " (?dependsOn@MPxNode@@UEBA?AVMStatus@@AEBVMPlug@@0AEA_N@Z)  D:\Program Files (x86)\MAYA\2016\devkit\devkitBase\devkit\plug-ins\manipOverride\manipOverride.obj  manipOverride`

`error LNK2001: unsolved external reference "public: virtual class MStatus __cdecl MPxContext::doPtrMoved(class MEvent &)" (?doPtrMoved@MPxContext@@UEAA?AVMStatus@@AEAVMEvent@@@Z) D:\Program Files (x86)\MAYA\2016\devkit\devkitBase\devkit\plug-ins\manipOverride\manipOverride.obj  manipOverride`

Maya2016, vs2012&vs2013. vs2012 is recommended by the official doc but still got the same errors.

I've checked the linker setting, OpenMaya.lib, OpenMayaUI.lib is included in the input libs. There're no similar problems found, anyone can help?

Comment: other examples seem fine, could be compiled and used in maya.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are trying to compile a plugin which has setting for 32 bit and now you compiling with x64. Probably you need to change the Solution Platform from you Configuration Manager.